# Allow certain users to only send emails to specific domains

Tags: email, postfix, filter

I have an email server with several domain and users.

I need block certain users from sending emails, but allow them to email specific domains.

Example:

user@domain.com block all outgoing emails except to example.com.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with `header_checks`.  Create an additional SMTP listener in `master.cf`, e.g. on port 10587.  In `header_checks` on your main listener (e.g. 587), do `FILTER localhost:10587` on mail with header `From: <restricted senders>`.

Then in the additional listener (port 10587), have a second set of header checks which do the `REJECT` action on all mail which does not match `To: <allowed search>`.